# localhost is wrong ip address

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, hosts

I'm having a bizarre problem. It started with postgresql-9.3 not installing. I found it couldn't find `localhost`.

I checked `/etc/hosts` and it has `localhost` properly as `127.0.0.1`

But when I

```
ping localhost
```

I get

```
PING localhost.Home (198.105.244.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

when I

```
whois 198.105.244.21
```

I get "SearchGuide Inc" in Colorado

How do I get my system to properly recognize localhost?

I'm running trusty tahr 14.04.2 lts

Here is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   ourcomp

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I had a typo earlier. It is now corrected.

Here is the output of `nslookup localhost`:

```
nslookup localhost
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost.Home
Address: 198.105.244.21
Name:   localhost.Home
Address: 198.105.254.21
```

Output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`ufw` status is inactive

`/etc/nsswitch` is blank

contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home
```

`ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:46904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2538766 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2538766 (2.5 MB)

p5p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:4d:a2:9b:3b:b9  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:b1:81:06:3d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.14  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:b1ff:fe81:63d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4212369 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:1142565 (1.1 MB)
```

Comment: `127.0.0.0` is the network address, `localhost` should be `127.0.0.1` (other IPs of this subnet is allowed although not prefarable)..could you please edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/hosts` ?

Comment: Do you have `iptables` or `ufw` or any other means of forwarding mechanisms configured ?

Comment: Not that I know of. That is, I didn't purposely configure them, but I don't know if something else I installed did.

Comment: `localhost.Home` looks like an mDNS hostname: please add the contents of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` files, and output of `ifconfig`

Comment: Run the command `echo 'hosts:          files mdns4 mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns' | sudo tee -a /etc/nsswitch.conf` and then check..

Comment: Not sure what you were going for, heemayl. That just added that literal  string to nsswitch.conf. Should  I not use the single quotes?

Comment: no quoting, just add the string to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`..

Comment: @heemayl I think the networking service may need to be restarted (or a reboot) for changes in nsswitch.conf to take effect?

Comment: @heemayl, thank you for that. After doing that and restarting, my system is behaving correctly. Two things are still bugging me, though. I still have these localhost.Home entries of 198.105.244.21 when I run nslookup. Why is that? What bugs me is this seems like a "band-aid" that may be masking something else. What exactly did that change do?

Comment: ok..remove `dns` (the last word) from the line we just added and then check..this is temporary for the purpose of checking..now use `nslookup` ..i think this is being resolved by your DNS, this will confirm us..

Comment: @heemayl removing dns broke my internet connection, but did not change the output of nslookup localhost, it still shows the localhost.home entries with the same IPs

Comment: @Trashman Well then..it was due to mdns....remove the `mdns4` entries and check to be sure of it..

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be missing relevant entries in the `/etc/nsswitch` configuration file.

While resolving hostnames to IP address, the GNU C library `libc` uses this file to get the sources and the order in which will be queried. The database name of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` involved here is `hosts`. There are also many other databases understood by `libc` e.g. `passwd`, `protocols` etc.

The databases are mentioned at the start of the line followed by the name of the sources to be queried. For example the required configuration for `hosts` database (used for finding IP address of a host) can take the form :

```
hosts:          files mdns4 dns
```

- `files` indicates that at first the relevant configuration files in `/etc` directory to be queried first, hence `/etc/hosts` is queried first
- Then mDNS (Multi-cast DNS) is used up to check if the IP can be retrieved
- Then DNS i.e. the name servers are queried for the IP address.

As your `/etc/nsswitch` configuration file does not contain anything, i would suggest you to put the default entries to the file :

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts: files mdns4 mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Check `man 5 nsswitch.conf` to get more idea.